# Cucumber step to pause and hand control over to the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber

I'm having trouble debugging cucumber steps due to unique conditions of the testing environment. I wish there was a step that could pause a selenium test and let me take over.

E.g.

```
Scenario: I want to take over here
  Given: A bunch of steps have already run
  When: I'm stuck on an error
  Then: I want to take control of the mouse
```

At that point I could interact with the application exactly as if I had done all the previous steps myself after running `rails server -e test`

Does such a step exist, or is there a way to make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the idea to dump the database. It doesn't let you continue work from the same page, but if you have the app running during the test, you can immediately act on the current state of things in another browser (not the one controlled by Selenium).

Here is the step:

```
When /I want to take control/i do
  exec "mysqldump -u root --password=* test > #{Rails.root}/support/snapshot.sql"
end
```

Because it is called by `exec`, DatabaseCleaner has no chance to truncate tables, so actually it's irrelevant that the command is a database dump. You don't have to import the sql to use the app in its current state, but it's there if you need it.

Comment: this does not work fully work. the browser remains alive. but the rails application is dead. can't really click around. I'd wish for a full interactive state.

Comment: This is a brilliant suggestion, thank you. I showed a minor variation below.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate ruby-debug into your Cucumber tests. Nathaniel Ritmeyer has directions [here](http://www.natontesting.com/2009/11/09/debugging-cucumber-tests-with-ruby-debug/) and [here](http://www.natontesting.com/2009/11/09/cucumber-step-definition-for-debugging/) which worked for me. You essentially require ruby-debug, start the debugger in your environment file, and then put "breakpoint" where ever you want to see what's going on. You can both interact with the browser/application and see the values of your ruby variables in the test. (I'm not sure whether it'll let you see the variables in your rails application itself - I'm not testing against a rails app to check that).

Comment: I've been using this. I still would like something to be able to interact manually with the browser because I need to look at HTML for Selenium testing.

Comment: When I break my tests with breakpoint, I can still interact with the browser. I wonder if you can't because of deeper integration into Rails?

Comment: I can interact with the current state of the broswer, but I can't continue to perform other actions because the debugger is active. If I allow the debugger to continue, the tests continue to run with no more chance for me to interact with the application.

Answer (score 1):

My teammate has done this using selenium, firebug a hook (@selenium_with_firebug)

Everything he learned came from this blogpost:

http://www.allenwei.cn/tips-add-firebug-extension-to-capybara/

Comment: This is still not the answer I'm looking for. I want to be able to continue clicking on links and performing actions within the application running in the test environment.

Answer (score 1):

Add the step

```
And show me the page
```

Where you want to interact with it

```
Scenario: I want to take over here
  Given: A bunch of steps have already run
  When: I'm stuck on an error
  Then show me the page
```

Comment: Still not the answer I'm looking for. That only allows you to see an html snapshot of the application at that moment. I want to keep running the application from that point.

Comment: What you're talking about would be awesome.  If someone knows how to do it, I'm definitely interested to use it myself.

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.natontesting.com/2009/11/09/debugging-cucumber-tests-with-ruby-debug/

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to @Reed G. Law for the idea of dumping the database. Then loading it into development allowed me to determine exactly why my cucumber feature was not impacting database state as I had expected. Here's my minor tweak to his suggestion:

```
When /Dump the database/i do
  `MYSQL_PWD=password mysqldump -u root my_test > #{Rails.root}/snapshot.sql`
  # To replicate state in development run:
  # `MYSQL_PWD=password mysql -u root my_development < snapshot.sql`
end
```

You can also use the following in feature/support/debugging.rb to let you step through the feature one step at a time:

```
# `STEP=1 cucumber` to pause after each step
AfterStep do |scenario|
  next unless ENV['STEP']
  unless defined?(@counter)
    puts "Stepping through #{scenario.title}"
    @counter = 0
  end
  @counter += 1
  print "At step ##{@counter} of #{scenario.steps.count}. Press Return to"\
        ' execute...'
  STDIN.getc
end
```